# "?" in intellisense when using entity framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have this poco class

```
public class MyEntity
{
  [Key]
  public int Id { get; set; }

  [Column("ComponentName")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

*it is only a snippet*!!!!

It is for quering a database that already exists, created in about 2008 by sql 2005 I guess. I used `app.config` to create it's connection string, I use `"Data Source=.\MSSQL2008;AttachDbFilename=C:\DbFiles\Comps.mdf;Initial Catalog=Comps;Integrated Security=True"` and my context connects successfully to the db file, and my repository queries. However this is the strange part.

It gets all 831 lines, which is the correct number of lines.

However intellisense gets to 14th entity then starts putting "?"
[image: Intellisense]

Why on earth is it doing this?

My poco class are mapped exactly right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is someone that can giv *exact reason* of this except some Visual Studio Architect. But this mostly happens when intelisence is not able (for 100 of reasons) to fetch the preview data, that is.

Don't think this is a problem for your app.

To check this, you may think of, showing content inside [Quick Watch](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/QuickWatch.aspx) window of Visual Studio, or print it out in [Output](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/3hk6fby3.aspx) window with [Console.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe timeout for data retrieval occurs? If it takes too long for debugger to evaluate an expression, it will stop doing that and no further expressions would be evaluated.

This can be confirmed if expanding results take some time (3-5 secs).